# Nodejs CoAP Server not receiving payload

Tags: javascript, arduino, payload, coap

I just created CoAP Client using Arduino and am able to send payload("hello") to the coap browser(installed from  mozilla browser). I can see it in browser, it receives.

Now I need to create my own |Nodejs server to receive my payload (say "hello") from Arduino client. How can I achieve it ?

**server**

```
var coap        = require('coap');
    var server      = coap.createServer();

// At this point, I checked from mozilla coap browser, sent "hello" and I am able to receive the HEX values. Same way, I tried to send it from Arduino, but did not print anything
    server.on('request', function(req, res) {
       console.log(req.payload);
    })

    // the default CoAP port is 5683
    server.listen(function() {
        var req = coap.request('coap://localhost');
        console.log('Listening on : 5683')

        req.on('response', function(res) {
            res.pipe(process.stdout);
        });

        req.end()
    });
```

**arduino**

```
void loop() {
  // send GET or PUT coap request to CoAP server.
  // To test, use libcoap, microcoap server...etc
   int msgid = coap.put(IPAddress(192,168,0,11), 5683, "light","1");
  Serial.println("Send Request");
  //int msgid1 = coap.get(IPAddress(192, 168, 0, 11), 5683, "time");

  delay(1000);
  coap.loop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Arduino, you should implement a coap server in firmware (not in Node).

Are you using [this](https://github.com/1248/microcoap) library?  If so then you should check out especially [this example](https://github.com/1248/microcoap/blob/master/microcoap.ino#L66) which reads from the ethernet peripheral, parses the packet, and then responds accordingly.

Pseudocode:

```
udp.setup()

while true
  p = udp.read()
  if(p == SUCCESSFUL_UDP_READ_FLAG)
    parsed = p.parse()
    if(parsed matches some condition)
      udp.respond(message regarding condition)
```

---

There's another example server with 2 endpoints [here](https://github.com/dgiannakop/Arduino-CoAP/blob/master/examples/CoAP_Use_Example/CoAP_Use_Example.ino).

The important parts are:

Inside `void setup()`:

```
coap.add_resource(&aSensor);
coap.add_resource(&bSensor);
```

And then inside `void loop()`:

```
coap.handler();
```